# Are there higher order, higher than 4th power, moments used to define statistically useful features?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

For example, in statistics, the 4th moment is used to define kurtosis. Is there any use for a fifth or sixth (etc.) moment?

Comment: In [this paper](http://theory.stanford.edu/~valiant/papers/KMV_c.pdf), six moments are used to estimate the parameters of a distribution which is a sum of two gaussians.

Comment: You could use [method of moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics)) with beyond 4th order moments.

Comment: For theoretical derivations, Yes. In practical applications, Rarely. // In interpreting sample statistics, even uses of skewness and kurtosis (especially as used in psychology and sociology) can be confusing and controversial.